# spring-data-rest generating wrong entity links in proxy setup

Tags: spring, apache, spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas

I deployed my Spring Boot application behind an Apache powered reverse proxy. This proxy already sets the headers `X-Forwarded-Proto` and `X-Forwarded-Host` correctly. However, spring-data-rest generates weird entity and enpoint links.
E.g. requesting the `news` resource:

`GET https://myproxyhost.net/api/news`

responses with this:

```
{
  "_embedded" : {
    "news" : [ {
      "title" : "Testnews",
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "https://myproxyhost.net/api/news/api/news/1"
        },
        "news" : {
          "href" : "https://myproxyhost.net/api/news/api/news/1{?projection}",
          "templated" : true
        }
      }
    } ]
  },
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "https://myproxyhost.net/api/news/api/news"
    },
    "profile" : {
      "href" : "https://myproxyhost.net/api/news/api/profile/news"
    },
    "search" : {
      "href" : "https://myproxyhost.net/api/news/api/news/search"
    }
  },
  "page" : {
    "size" : 20,
    "totalElements" : 1,
    "totalPages" : 1,
    "number" : 0
  }
}
```

As you can see the links are somehow doubled and I have no idea why. The only spring-data-rest specific property I use is:

```
spring.data.rest.base-path=/api
```

Additionally in my local setup everything works fine, so I guess the proxy is somehow responsible for this.

Has anybody an idea what is going wrong here? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was an incorrect configuration of the ReverseProxy settings which led to urls like

```
http://proxiedhost.net:8080//api/news
```

Which led therefore to the weird urls mentioned in the question above.